# Laravel:SUM OF MULTIPLIED COLUMN

Tags: laravel-5

I have table named `particulars` in my sql database, Am using two rows from two tables such as price from particular table and quantity from req table

```
  $particulars =DB::table('particulars as A')
        ->leftjoin('reqs as B', function ($join) {
            $join->on('A.particular_id', '=', 'B.particular_id');
        })
        ->whereBetween('B.date_issued', [$start_date, $end_date]) >select('A.item_name','A.unit','A.price','B.quantity_issued',DB::raw('sum(A.price*B.quantity_issued) as total_cost'))
        ->groupBy('A.particular_id')
        ->get();
```

I want to get sum after multiplication of price and quantity means sum of Total cost that I get after multiplication.
Here is My View

```
    <table cellspacing="0">
    <thead style="background-color: grey">
    <tr style="">
        <th >Quantity</th>
        <th>price</th>
        <th>Total Cost</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> @foreach($particulars as $particular)
        <tr>
           <td>{{$particular->quantity_issued}}</td>             
            <td>&nbsp;{{$particular->price}}</td>
            <td>&nbsp;{{$particular->total_cost}}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" style="text-align: center">Total</td>
        <td class="total"></td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: I mean sum of new generated column(total)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in there.

```
->whereBetween('B.date_issued', [$start_date, $end_date])>select
```

Should be ->select